# Connectedness of Quot schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, hilbert-schemes, path-connected

Let $X$ be a connected projective scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ and $E$ a coherent sheaf on $X$. Consider the Quot scheme $\operatorname{Quot}_X(E,P)$ of quotients of $E$ of fixed Hilbert polynomial $P$. As far as I know, this scheme is connected at least in the following cases:

1. for Hilbert schemes on $\mathbb{P}^n$ (by Hartshorne)
2. for punctual Quot schemes on smooth surfaces (by Fogarty, Ellingsrud–Lehn, Baranovski, etc.).

Are there any other known cases for which $\operatorname{Quot}_X(E,P)$ is connected? Could you give some examples where the connectedness fails? I am particularly interested in higher dimensions or singular surfaces/varieties.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest example when connectedness fails is the Hilbert scheme of lines on a quadric surface:
$$
\mathrm{Hilb}_{1+t}(\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1) = \mathbb{P}^1 \sqcup \mathbb{P}^1,
$$
where the polarization is by the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1,1)$.

Comment: You cannot “fix” this by using a “refined” Hilbert polynomial: let $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}^3\times\mathbb{P}^9$ be the universal quadric surface, and let $X$ be $Y\times\mathbb{P}^1$.  The cone of effective curve classes on this Fano manifold is the cone of triples of nonnegative integers: the degrees of the projections to $\mathbb{P}^1$, to $\mathbb{P}^3$, and to $\mathbb{P}^9$.  Consider the curve class where the triple is $(1,4,0)$.  The actual curves of arithmetic genus $0$ project to curves in $Y$ in a fiber ,I.e., a quartic  in a quadric surface. The curve class might be $(2,2)$ or $(3,1)$.

Comment: Please note that this $X$ is a Fano manifold.  This does not contradict Cohen-Jones-Segal, because they require the curve class to be far from the boundary of the cone of effective curve classes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be an irreducible variety, $E$ a locally free sheaf on $X$, and $n \geq 0$ an integer. The Quot scheme $\textrm{Quot}_X(E,n)$ is connected by Thm. 1.4 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.11817.pdf). To achieve disconnectedness, probably one has to look at nonconstant polynomials, as Sasha's example suggests.

Comment: do you think it is necessary to assume that $X$ is irreducible (rather than connected). It seems to me that the result should be true if $X$ is just connected.

Comment: you're probably right!